# JQuery late bind Accordion UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div that is dynamically created on the server and returned to the page via ajax using Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: pathSite,
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function (view) {

                            //add view content
                            $('#pageContent').html(view);

                        },
                        async: true
                    });
```

Now the problem is that inside that HTML returned by the ajax function is a div that is supposed to be an accordion (JQuery UI), so I need to use late binding for the UI build method, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#accordionForm').live("ready", function () {
    $('#accordionForm').accordion();
});
});
```

But I know that "ready" is not a valid event for live method, so please tell me if there is another workaround for this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just create the accordion right after the new div is added?

Comment: Possibly `load` might work (but I've not tried it, hence posting this as a comment, not an answer): `$('#accordionForm').live("ready", function () {/* stuff */});` But using the `success` callback function would probably be easier and more reliable.

Comment: Creating the accordion after the new div is added didn't worked

Comment: It almost certainly won't solve your problem, but this weekend is the [Cotati Accordion Festival](http://www.cotatifest.com/). :-)

Comment: I already tried the load event and it didn't worked

Comment: David is right. Just put the statement at the end of success function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add it to your success function, this will ensure it runs after the ajax calls has completed.

```
success: function (view) {
                            //add view content 
                           $('#pageContent').html(view);

                            //convert to accordian
                            $('#accordionForm').accordion();
                        },
```

Comment: not a good thing, user will need to wait when pages gets loaded.